# Using Protocols to call a Function in Another Class

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I need to call a function named xyz, which is located in my ViewController class, and call it in my Cell class. 
This is the code that I use:
ViewController

```
    import UIKit
    protocol abc {
       func xyz()
    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController, abc {
     func xyz() {
       print("Hi")
     }
     override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let obj = Cell.init()
      obj.delegate = self
     }
    }
```

Then for my Cell class I use

```
    var delegate: abc?

    func update() {
    self.delegate?.xyz()
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of 
var delegate: xyz?

I would recommend to use 
var delegate: abc?

This way you can use it any other class which implement abc protocol.

Comment: That still doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: It doesn't print hi when I call func update from Cell.

Comment: It says Thread 1: fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.